# onSubmit javascript not visibly changing a button's value

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm working with Django's admin interface, and wanted to add simple double click protection to the Save button.

In submit_line.html:

```
{% if show_save %}<input type="submit" value={% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" id="_save" name="_save" {{onclick_attrib}}/>{% endif %}
```

The form (change_form.html):

```
<form {% if has_file_field %}enctype="multipart/form-data" {% endif %}action="{{ form_url }}" method="post" id="{{ opts.module_name }}_form" onSubmit="document.getElementById('_save').value="Please wait.."; alert(document.getElementById('_save').value);">
```

In admin_modify.py:

```
'onclick_attrib':(opts.get_ordered_objects() and change and 'onClick="submitOrderForm();"' or '')
```

(this ends up being '' because there's nothing in the resulting html page.)

The issue is that **the Submit button's text is not changed when it's clicked.** **The alert shows the expected value, "Please wait", but the button still says Save.** I want to change it to be disabled when clicked as well, but that won't work either.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Is `onclick_atrib` misspelled in `admin_modify.py`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I've corrected it.